# How to build Directed acyclic graph using Pyro in python?

Tags: python, directed-acyclic-graphs, inference, bayesian-networks, pyro.ai

Can any one halp me how to use Pyro to build directed acyclic graph and calculate inference?

Let consider this graph:

```
A---> B <-----C
```

`A` successful probability `0.6` and `C` successful probability `0.7`

Can we calculate `P(A,B,C)` and `P(B|A,C)` using `Pyro` in python?

Comment: can you show what you've tried?